# Trying to parse through a XML file using Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, lxml, minidom

Hoping y'all can help me out.  I am relatively new to python.  I have what I need working in powershell but it is so much easier to access the XML elements through the powershell objects than Python it seems. In powershell, I can simply do

```
[xml]$test = Get-Content .\test.xml
```

and then iterate through the object to find the information I need.  Full disclosure, while XML seems easy I get tripped up with the lingo. Here is a small version of the XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--DISA STIG Viewer :: 2.9-->
<CHECKLIST>
    <ASSET>
        <ROLE>None</ROLE>
        <ASSET_TYPE>Computing</ASSET_TYPE>
        <HOST_NAME></HOST_NAME>
        <HOST_IP></HOST_IP>
        <HOST_MAC></HOST_MAC>
        <HOST_FQDN></HOST_FQDN>
        <TECH_AREA></TECH_AREA>
        <TARGET_KEY>2266</TARGET_KEY>
        <WEB_OR_DATABASE>false</WEB_OR_DATABASE>
        <WEB_DB_SITE></WEB_DB_SITE>
        <WEB_DB_INSTANCE></WEB_DB_INSTANCE>
    </ASSET>
    <STIGS>
        <iSTIG>
            <STIG_INFO>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>version</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>5</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>classification</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>UNCLASSIFIED</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>customname</SID_NAME>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>stigid</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>McAfee_VirusScan88_Managed_Client</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>description</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>The McAfee VirusScan Managed Client STIG is published as a tool to improve the security of Department of Defense (DoD) information systems. The requirements are derived from the NIST 800-53 and related documents. Comments or proposed revisions to this document should be sent via e-mail to the following address: disa.stig_spt@mail.mil.</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>filename</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>U_McAfee_VirusScan88_Managed_Client_STIG_V5R21_Manual-xccdf.xml</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>releaseinfo</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>Release: 21 Benchmark Date: 25 Oct 2019</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>title</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>McAfee VirusScan 8.8 Managed Client STIG</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>uuid</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>1a441b95-b269-4423-8a40-a34f56441f5a</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>notice</SID_NAME>
                    <SID_DATA>terms-of-use</SID_DATA>
                </SI_DATA>
                <SI_DATA>
                    <SID_NAME>source</SID_NAME>
                </SI_DATA>
            </STIG_INFO>
            <VULN>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Vuln_Num</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>V-6453</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Severity</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>high</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Group_Title</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>DTAM001-McAfee VirusScan Control Panel </ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Rule_ID</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>SV-55134r1_rule</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Rule_Ver</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>DTAM001</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Rule_Title</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>McAfee VirusScan On-Access General Policies must be configured to enable on-access scanning at system startup.
</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Vuln_Discuss</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>For antivirus software to be effective, it must be running at all times, beginning from the point of the system's initial startup. Otherwise, the risk is greater for viruses, trojans, and other malware infecting the system during that startup phase.
</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>IA_Controls</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA></ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Check_Content</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>From the ePO server console System Tree, select the Systems tab, select the asset to be checked, select Actions, select Agent, and select Modify Policies on a Single System. From the product pull down list, select VirusScan Enterprise 8.8.0. Select from the Policy column the policy associated with the On-Access General Policies. Under the General tab, locate the "Enable on-access scanning:" label. Ensure the "Enable on-access scanning at system startup" option is selected.

Criteria:  If the "Enable on-access scanning at startup" option is selected, this is not a finding. 

On the client machine, use the Windows Registry Editor to navigate to the following key:
HKLM\Software\McAfee\ (32-bit)
HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\McAfee\ (64-bit)
SystemCore\VSCore\On Access Scanner\McShield\Configuration

Criteria:  If the value of bStartDisabled is 0, this is not a finding. If the value is 1, this is a finding.</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Fix_Text</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>From the ePO server console System Tree, select the Systems tab, select the asset to be checked, select Actions, select Agent, and select Modify Policies on a Single System. From the product pull down list, select VirusScan Enterprise 8.8.0. Select from the Policy column the policy associated with the On-Access General Policies. Under the General tab, locate the "Enable on-access scanning:" label. Select the "Enable on-access scanning at system startup" option. Select Save.</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>False_Positives</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA></ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>False_Negatives</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA></ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Documentable</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>false</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Mitigations</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA></ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Potential_Impact</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA></ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Third_Party_Tools</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA></ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Mitigation_Control</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA></ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Responsibility</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>System Administrator</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Security_Override_Guidance</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA></ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Check_Content_Ref</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>M</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Weight</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>10.0</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Class</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>Unclass</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>STIGRef</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>McAfee VirusScan 8.8 Managed Client STIG :: Version 5, Release: 21 Benchmark Date: 25 Oct 2019</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>TargetKey</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>2266</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STIG_DATA>
                    <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>CCI_REF</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
                    <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>CCI-001242</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
                </STIG_DATA>
                <STATUS>Not_Reviewed</STATUS>
                <FINDING_DETAILS></FINDING_DETAILS>
                <COMMENTS></COMMENTS>
                <SEVERITY_OVERRIDE></SEVERITY_OVERRIDE>
                <SEVERITY_JUSTIFICATION></SEVERITY_JUSTIFICATION>
            </VULN>
        </iSTIG>
    </STIGS>
</CHECKLIST>
```

I know there are a couple different ways to do this, but I was trying trough minidom first

```
import xml.dom.minidom
doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(r'C:\Temp\test.xml')
print (doc.nodeName)
root = doc.firstChild.tagName
root
```

Which results in printing out CHECKLIST which is indeed the root of the document.  Now in powershell, I would do root.STIG.iSTIG.STIG_INFO.SI_DATA and start a loop through there but having trouble wrapping my head around why this is so much more different.

I also tried to begin with ElementTree but didn't get far

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
doc = ET.parse(r'C:\Temp\test.xml').getroot()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here without necessarily giving me the written code as an answer?  I already transformed my XML using lxml and was able to output the below file which is great but having trouble with the next step.

Thanks!

Comment: Given your sample xml, what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: @JackFleeting  Wow yeah I guess I probably should have added that I would like to pull out each <VULN> and make a list of lists I think is what I am trying to do.  Like I said I am really new to Python but I find the best way for me to learn is to dive right into an actual real-world example.

Comment: See answer; let me know if it points you to the right direction.

Comment: @JackFleeting ahhhh yes xpaths I've never used them before but I think I see how they work in your example.  I'll play with it an let you know.  Thanks!!

Comment: "I would like to pull out each <VULN> and make a list of lists". What should this list ot lists look like?

Comment: @mzjn basically, I would want to pull out each vulnerability Id, severity, description, check text, etc.  That way I can loop through the lists and when I find a matching vulnerability ID, be able to pull the other information.  I think a list of lists is the right approach

Comment: I find this unclear. "A matching vulnerability ID". What is supposed to match? Please edit the question and show us what the wanted output is.

Comment: @mzjn Well I'm not looking for the answer I was looking for guidance on what direction to go in to extract items from this XML file.  JackFleeting provided a viable way for me.  I am fine handling to loops to pull in data but I'm not sure if a list of lists is the right way to store the data.  Basically I will have a key value and whenever I find a matching key value I want to pull out other associated values.  I am using this to create I guess a giant lookup table of sorts.

Comment: OK. If Jack Fleeting's answer is good enough, upvote it or mark it as accepted. I find it hard to provide "guidance" without knowing what the end goal is. I don't  understand what "matching key" or "associated values" refer to. Btw, when someone asks for clarifications, it is usually better to edit the question instead of adding comments.

Comment: @mzjn I appreciate the follow ups.  Kind of new to this platform unusually just answer the questions.  Basically I want to create a lookup table and I don't know  if a list of lists as the right representation of my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for a general direction, try something like this and modify it to your needs:

```
from lxml import etree

stig = """your xml above"""
parser = etree.XMLParser()

tree = etree.fromstring(stig, parser)
items = tree.xpath('//iSTIG/STIG_INFO//SI_DATA')
for item in items:
    print(item.xpath('string(SID_NAME/text())')," ",item.xpath('string(SID_DATA/text())'))
```

Output:

```
version   5
classification   UNCLASSIFIED
```

etc.

Obviously, instead of printing you can add each item to a list and so on.